# How to hide extension of my asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes

I have created a website in asp.net application. Which contains hundreds of pages for Insert Update Edit and Delete.

I need URL rewriting without doing too much of code. Please guide me.

My Application URL like.

> http://domain/Users/index.aspx http://domain/Users/product.aspx
>   http://domain/Users/product.aspx?catid=1
>   http://domain/Users/product.aspx?typeid=1
>   http://domain/Users/product.aspx?editid=1&type=2

I want to hide the .aspx from whole application and also the URL doesn't show the .aspx page url if user open directly http://domain/Users/product.aspx?typeid=1.

Please let me know if any solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `FriendlyUrls` which will enable you to achieve what you want. Firstly you will need to install the package which you can do by using `NuGet Console`

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls
```

Then in your `RouteConfig Class` you want something like below which should do the trick.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
}
```

There's a handy article **[here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)** which I reccomend you read.